# How to call grab the value of a button inside the iframe using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have 2 html pages (**a.html** and **b.html**). I have made an `<iframe>` and set b.html as a source of a.html. But how do I call at a.html to grab the value of b.html button using jquery via class name? FYI: Both are in the same domain. How can I achieve that?

**a.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>a.html</title>
    <script>
        function howToGetValueOfBtn() {

        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe src="b.html"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

**b.html**

```
<html>
<body>
    <input type="button" value="getThisValue" class="btn"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for all the helps in advance!

Comment: if you want to share value between the html pages, use `localStorage` to save on b.html and get on a.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var button_value = $('iframe').contents().find('.btn').val();
```

But it would be best if you give your button an `Id`

```
var button_value = $('iframe').contents().find('#btn_Value').val(); 
<input type="button" value="getThisValue" class="btn" id="btn_Value"/>
```

Hope this helps